# What is the justification for FIFA's support of states with limited recognition?

Tags: statehood

FIFA recognizes several countries or rather I would say 'states' as a single federation unit like Kosovo, Guam, Gibraltar, etc. which are not recognized or partially recognized.

Supporters of this policy argue that it may help the people living there to have an opportunity to represent their states from which they have been generally discarded for years.

My question is, what is the formal/legal justification for FIFA's support and recognizing these states as single federation members? Doesn't it break the ties Gibraltar have with Britain or Guam has with US?

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE! This site is for objective questions about governments, policies and political processes. Asking for opinions is off-topic.

Comment: Hi Aneek, your question looked a bit opinionated and it has received several close-votes. I have attempted to salvage it. Please review the edit. Mind that you are free to rollback my edit if it contradicts your original intent.

Comment: While FIFA governs a sport, I'm not sure we'd call that politics in the typical sense. FIFA is also corrupt, so I'm not sure they even care much about laws anyways. :)

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, it's just a legacy from a time FIFA did not have so much influence and did not care too much about things like what is a country, not a principled stance that anybody would try to justify. I doubt Gibraltar or Guam would be admitted under current FIFA rules regarding new members.

Kosovo is an interesting case, as it is much more recent and politically sensitive. There have been many discussions but [it still isn't a full *bona fide* member of FIFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosovo_national_football_team).

[See also this questions on the sports website for a related discussion](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/why-great-britain-or-england-scotland-wales-ireland-in-different-sport/10676#10676)

Comment: Do charter members pay fees to FIFA? If so, it may simply be a case of "why would we turn away free money?"

Comment: @user4012 Good question. I think most of the money comes from sponsorship and TV deals and FIFA actually gives money to small federations (in exchange for votes, that's how Blatter and before him Havelange kept a tight control over the whole organisation).